# groupby and calculate mean but keeping all columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to calculate the mean of the numeric columns using groupby but maintaining all columns. An example of a dataframe from 7 columns is here:

```
tracking_id gene_id gene_short_name tss_id  locus   FPKM-1  FPKM-2
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   Tss1231 1:4490927-4496413   0.611985    232
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   Ts412   1:4490927-4496413   12  21
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   Ts56    1:4490927-4496413   2   213
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   TS512   1:4490927-4496413   0.611985    5
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   TS12241 1:4490927-4496413   0.611985    51
ENSMUSG00000096126  ENSMUSG00000096126  Gm22307 TS124   1:4529016-4529123   35  1
ENSMUSG00000096126  ENSMUSG00000096126  Gm22307 TS-1824 1:4529016-4529123   1   2
ENSMUSG00000096126  ENSMUSG00000096126  Gm22307 TS1249082   1:4529016-4529123   2   5
ENSMUSG00000088000  ENSMUSG00000088000  Gm25493 TS1290328   1:4723276-4723379   0   1
ENSMUSG00000098104  ENSMUSG00000098104  Gm6085  TS01239-1   1:4687933-4689403   0.0743559   6
ENSMUSG00000033845  ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15  TSS31014,TSS82987,TSS82990,TSS86849 1:4773205-4785739   79.1154 7
ENSMUSG00000093015  ENSMUSG00000093015  Gm22463 TSS79849    1:5644644-5644745   0   1
ENSMUSG00000025905  ENSMUSG00000025905  Oprk1   TSS15316,TSS3878,TSS6226,TSS65522   1:5588492-5606131   0   6
ENSMUSG00000033774  ENSMUSG00000033774  Npbwr1  TSS69693    1:5913706-5917398   0   8
ENSMUSG00000033793  ENSMUSG00000033793  Atp6v1h TSS4651 1:5083172-5162549   24.2386 9
ENSMUSG00000087247  ENSMUSG00000087247  Fam150a TSS42747    1:6359330-6394731   0.502804    1
```

I would like to group by the first 3 columns, and keep columns 4 and 5 in my output (best would be the first row of each repeated columns 1 to 3) and then calculate the mean of the numeric columns at the end. I have written this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('grouping.txt')
grouped = df.groupby(list(df.columns[0:3]), sort=False).mean()
```

The output is:

```
tracking_id gene_id gene_short_name FPKM-1  FPKM-2
ENSMUSG00000025902  ENSMUSG00000025902  Sox17   3.167191    104.4
ENSMUSG00000096126  ENSMUSG00000096126  Gm22307 12.66666667 2.666666667
ENSMUSG00000088000  ENSMUSG00000088000  Gm25493 0   1
ENSMUSG00000098104  ENSMUSG00000098104  Gm6085  0.0743559   6
ENSMUSG00000033845  ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15  79.1154 7
ENSMUSG00000093015  ENSMUSG00000093015  Gm22463 0   1
ENSMUSG00000025905  ENSMUSG00000025905  Oprk1   0   6
ENSMUSG00000033774  ENSMUSG00000033774  Npbwr1  0   8
ENSMUSG00000033793  ENSMUSG00000033793  Atp6v1h 24.2386 9
ENSMUSG00000087247  ENSMUSG00000087247  Fam150a 0.502804    1
```

The above is an output but is missing columns 4 (TSS) and 5 (locus) of the input file. How can I retain those 2 columns (their values are different and hence cant be part of the groupby columns. Keeping ANY of the values of the columns is OK with me, as long as one of the grouped by is there).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can merge the results of your groupby() aggregation back into a deduped version of your original DataFrame. Perhaps something like this:

```
# identify the columns we want to aggregate by; this could
# equivalently be defined as list(df.columns[0:3])
group_cols = ['tracking_id', 'gene_id', 'gene_short_name']
# identify the columns which we want to average; this could
# equivalently be defined as list(df.columns[4:])
metric_cols = ['FPKM-1', 'FPKM-2']

# create a new DataFrame with a MultiIndex consisting of the group_cols
# and a column for the mean of each column in metric_cols
aggs = df.groupby(group_cols)[metric_cols].mean()
# remove the metric_cols from df because we are going to replace them
# with the means in aggs
df.drop(metric_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
# dedupe to leave only one row with each combination of group_cols
# in df
df.drop_duplicates(subset=group_cols, keep='last', inplace=True)
# add the mean columns from aggs into df
df = df.merge(right=aggs, right_index=True, left_on=group_cols, how='right')
```

Comment: the output ended up being the same as input except the last columns were replaced by averages. dont think it worked.

Comment: @BioProgram - I misunderstood your question. Updated my answer to another possible approach...

Comment: ur script works. Can you please explain the reset_index, then the topping of columns. I couldnt figure out what is actually being done in lines 3, 4 and 5. Also, the way you wrote the groupby()[].mean() is different form what I have written.. not sure how it still worked. Would appreciate if you can elaborate a bit

Comment: by the way, 'take_last=True' should be 'keep='last''

Comment: I've added some comments. Hopefully that makes it more clear. The [metric_cols] in the groupby() line isn't required, but I think it makes the code cleaner. It explicitly states which columns will be averaged, rather than letting Pandas simply average all numeric columns.

Comment: Yeah - keep='last' is now preferred. I'm still on an old version of pandas :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [aggregation, with a dict of functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns) to apply to each column. I'm using `lambda`s and the string version of Pandas (dataframe) functions, so that Pandas will pick up `mean()` automatically.

```
grouped = df.groupby(list(df.columns[0:3]), sort=False).agg(
    {'FPKM-1': 'mean', 'FPKM-2': 'mean',
     'tss_id': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 'locus': lambda x: x.iloc[0]})
print(grouped)
```

gives:

```
tracking_id        gene_id            gene_short_name                               tss_id     FPKM-1      FPKM-2              locus
ENSMUSG00000025902 ENSMUSG00000025902 Sox17                                        Tss1231   3.167191  104.400000  1:4490927-4496413
ENSMUSG00000096126 ENSMUSG00000096126 Gm22307                                        TS124  12.666667    2.666667  1:4529016-4529123
ENSMUSG00000088000 ENSMUSG00000088000 Gm25493                                    TS1290328   0.000000    1.000000  1:4723276-4723379
ENSMUSG00000098104 ENSMUSG00000098104 Gm6085                                     TS01239-1   0.074356    6.000000  1:4687933-4689403
ENSMUSG00000033845 ENSMUSG00000033845 Mrpl15           TSS31014,TSS82987,TSS82990,TSS86849  79.115400    7.000000  1:4773205-4785739
ENSMUSG00000093015 ENSMUSG00000093015 Gm22463                                     TSS79849   0.000000    1.000000  1:5644644-5644745
ENSMUSG00000025905 ENSMUSG00000025905 Oprk1              TSS15316,TSS3878,TSS6226,TSS65522   0.000000    6.000000  1:5588492-5606131
ENSMUSG00000033774 ENSMUSG00000033774 Npbwr1                                      TSS69693   0.000000    8.000000  1:5913706-5917398
ENSMUSG00000033793 ENSMUSG00000033793 Atp6v1h                                      TSS4651  24.238600    9.000000  1:5083172-5162549
ENSMUSG00000087247 ENSMUSG00000087247 Fam150a                                     TSS42747   0.502804    1.000000  1:6359330-6394731
```

Comment: thank you, that works, except for one thing. The FPKM-1.. columns at the end could range up to 1000 columns. It is always after the 5th (locus) column though. Also, in your script, the locus column seem to have shifted to the end. How can i have that done for mean without having to the egg 1000 times and locus column to stay where it is supposed to.

Comment: You can create the dict programmatically with e.g. a dict comprehension through the relevant columns. Where the locus column is doesn't matter for calculations, that's only in the eye of the beholder; you can specify the columns in the order necessary as index to `grouped[list_of_column_names_in_order']`.